# Buffered Image taking up cpu when scaled up to over 8k pixels

Tags: java, swing, graphics, bufferedimage

I am having a problem with cpu taking up a full processor when scaling a Buffered image from 1920 x 224 to 8777 x 1024 and painting it at 30 fps.

I tried only displaying the height and width of the jpanel by using.

```
drawImage(img, dx1, dy1, dx2, dy2, sx1, sy1, sx2, sy2, observer)
```

but still a major spike in cpu.

My test code is as follows:

[image: test.png]

```
package test;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel{

int frame = 0;
BufferedImage srcImg;
BufferedImage backgroundImg;
Timer timer = new Timer();

public GamePanel(){
try {
    srcImg = ImageIO.read(new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TJPy.png"));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

backgroundImg = new BufferedImage(8777, 1024, BufferedImage.TRANSLUCENT);
Graphics2D g2 = backgroundImg.createGraphics();
g2.setRenderingHint(
    RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
    RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR);
g2.drawImage(srcImg, 0, 0,8777, 1024, null);
g2.dispose();

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    repaint();
  }
}, 1000/30, 1000/30);
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
super.paintComponent(g);
frame++;
//g.drawImage(backgroundImg, frame%backgroundImg.getWidth(),0, this);
g.drawImage(backgroundImg, 0, 0, 600, 1024, frame, 0, frame+this.getWidth(), backgroundImg.getHeight(),null);
g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
g.drawString("" + frame, 20, 50);
}

@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
return new Dimension(600,1024);
}


public static void main(String[] args){
GamePanel panel = new GamePanel();

JFrame f = new JFrame();

//f.setBounds(0,0,400,400);
f.getContentPane().add(panel);
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
f.pack();
f.setVisible(true);

}

}
```

EDIT: i found that this way reduces cpu but only by about 20%, im looking to get it down to only using 0 - 10% cpu like when im not displaying such a large image

My question is what is the most cpu efficient way of painting a buffered image.

Comment: 1) `public void run() {
    while(true){
        repaint();`  Use a Swing based `Timer` for animation. 2) `g.drawImage(backgroundImg, 0,0, null);` should be `g.drawImage(backgroundImg, 0,0, this);` 3) Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use them consistently.

Comment: Umm.. do you realize the `Thread` was never started?!?

Comment: Add thread.start() to run the thread and watch the result to improve your code.

Answer (score 2):

Try this SSCCE formed from the code and see if it behaves more as you expect.  It seems pretty fast here:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.net.URL;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable{

int frame = 0;
BufferedImage srcImg;
BufferedImage backgroundImg;

public GamePanel(){
    try {
        srcImg = ImageIO.read(new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TJPy.png"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    backgroundImg = new BufferedImage(8777, 1024, BufferedImage.TRANSLUCENT);
    Graphics2D g2 = backgroundImg.createGraphics();
    g2.setRenderingHint(
        RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
        RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR);
    g2.drawImage(srcImg, 0, 0,8777, 1024, null);
    g2.dispose();
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    frame--;
    g.drawImage(backgroundImg, frame%backgroundImg.getWidth(),0, this);
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.drawString("" + frame, 20, 50);
}

@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(600,1024);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while(true){
        repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000/30);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    GamePanel panel = new GamePanel();
    Thread thread = new Thread(panel);

    JFrame f = new JFrame();

    //f.setBounds(0,0,400,400);
    f.getContentPane().add(panel);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
    thread.start();
}

}
```

### [image: Game Loop using Thread]

Here is the equivalent using a Swing based `Timer`.  OK, not much better, but still better practice.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.net.URL;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel {

int frame = 0;
BufferedImage srcImg;
BufferedImage backgroundImg;

public GamePanel(){
    try {
        srcImg = ImageIO.read(new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TJPy.png"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    backgroundImg = new BufferedImage(8777, 1024, BufferedImage.TRANSLUCENT);
    Graphics2D g2 = backgroundImg.createGraphics();
    g2.setRenderingHint(
        RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
        RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR);
    g2.drawImage(srcImg, 0, 0,8777, 1024, null);
    g2.dispose();
    ActionListener al = new ActionListener()  {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            repaint();
        }
    };
    Timer timer = new Timer(1000/30, al);
    timer.start();
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    frame--;
    g.drawImage(backgroundImg, frame%backgroundImg.getWidth(),0, this);
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.drawString("" + frame, 20, 50);
}

@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(600,1024);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    GamePanel panel = new GamePanel();

    JFrame f = new JFrame();

    f.getContentPane().add(panel);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

[image: Game Loop - Timer]

Comment: Still eating my whole processor, my only other thought would be to split the image into multiple images and load them like chunks

Comment: *"Still eating my whole processor,.."*  Have you changed it to use a `Timer`?!?  Batteries not included. That code as seen goes into an infinite loop.  Of course it would tie up the CPU.  **If you have changed it to use `Timer`, show us the new source as an edit to the question.**

Comment: even with the timer its eating up a whole processor

Comment: *"split the image into multiple images and load them like chunks"*  I doubt that will help.  The Java painting system does a lot of clever optimization.  One example is that if we request to paint a pixel, but it lies outside the visible bounds, the painting system will just skip it.

Comment: Runs smoothly and profiles cleanly on Mac OS X, Java 7.

Comment: well when it draws a smaller image, say 3000 px its takes no cpu its just when we make it this size